# Configure Eclipse PyDev to notify me when Python script is done running

Tags: eclipse, windows, pydev

Is any way to configure Eclipse PyDev to get notified me when a Python script is done running (e.g. popup in icon tray)? I use Eclipse on Windows 7, Kubuntu 14.04 and Max OS X 10.10, all x64.

Comment: I haven't found any answer so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.